# Google Map marker tooltip on all markers, TypeError: projection is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
cTooltip.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

cTooltip.prototype.draw1 = function(pos, content, margin){
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.cssText = 'z-index:9999;cursor:pointer;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;text-align:center;margin:'+margin;
  if(content){
    div.innerHTML = content;
  }
  if(pos){

    $(markers_sets).each(function () {
       if (this.id == per.markers_set) {
            m_settings = this.settings;
       }
    });

    var markersOffset = (typeof m_settings.markers_offset !== 'undefined' ? parseInt(m_settings.markers_offset) : 7);

    var width = $('.vipul_'+tooltipCount).outerWidth() / 2;
    pin_center = 56 - width;
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(pos);
    div.style.left = (position.x - 64 + pin_center + markersOffset) + 'px';
    div.style.top = (position.y - 40) + 'px';
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }

tooltipCount++;
}
```

When I call cTooltip on mousehover event, its working but when I call it directly inside loop, first tooltip can be seen but after second loop error is coming

```
div.onmouseover = function() {
      if (tool_tip_timeout != null) {
        clearTimeout(tool_tip_timeout);
        tool_tip_timeout = null;
      }
      if (display_tip && !this.hasClass('hideTooltip')) {
        var tool_tip_html ='';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-blue vipul_'+tooltipCount+'">';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-pin-container">';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-text">' + getTooltip(pos) + '</div>';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-pin"></div>';
        tool_tip_html += '</div>';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-shadow"><img src="/ver4/images/bubble-shadow.png"></div>';
        tool_tip_html += '</div>';
        tool_tip_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          //tooltip.draw1(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(l[marker_lat_i]), parseFloat(l[marker_lng_i])), tool_tip_html, '-' + (parseInt(md.groups_top)) + 'px 0px 0px ' + Math.abs(parseInt(md.groups_left) - parseInt(md.groups_width) - 3) + 'px');
          tooltip.draw1(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(l[marker_lat_i]), parseFloat(l[marker_lng_i])), tool_tip_html, '-' + (parseInt(md.groups_top) + 6) + 'px 0px 0px 0px');
        }, 500);
      }
      display_tip = false;
    };
```

Error is shown below, above written code inside mousehover event is working but I want to show all the tooltips on all marker after loading map instead of using mousehover event.

```
TypeError: projection is undefined

var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(pos);
```

Rest of the code

```
function cMarker(opt_options) {
  this.setValues(opt_options);
  var group = this.get('group');
  var unique_groups = this.get('unique_groups');
  var l = this.get('data');
  var descr = this.get('description');
  var pos = this.get('pos');
  var tooltip = this.tooltip = this.get('tooltip');
  this.r = pos;
  var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
  var mb = parseInt(md.markers_top) + 40;




   div.onmouseover = function() {
      if (tip_content != "") {
        if (tool_tip_timeout != null) {
          clearTimeout(tool_tip_timeout);
          tool_tip_timeout = null;
        }
        if (display_tip && !this.hasClass('hideTooltip')) {
        var tool_tip_html ='';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-blue vipul_'+tooltipCount+'">';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-pin-container">';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-text">' + tip_content + '</div>';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-pin"></div>';
        tool_tip_html += '</div>';
        tool_tip_html += '<div class="maptive-bubble-shadow"><img src="/ver4/images/bubble-shadow.png"></div>';
        tool_tip_html += '</div>';
          tool_tip_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            tooltip.draw(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(l[marker_lat_i]), parseFloat(l[marker_lng_i])), tool_tip_html, '-' + (parseInt(md.markers_top) + 6) + 'px 0px 0px 0px');
          }, 500);
        }
        display_tip=false;
      }
    };
}

I want to draw tooltip on all markers, that why instead of mousehover I need to call it on load event or by simply by placing it outside that mousehover event but error is projection is undefined after displaying one tooltip.
```

Comment: where do you call `draw1`? (this method will not be called automatically by the API)

Comment: I'm calling it out side mousehover event, please check above written mousehover event. This event is called inside function cMarker(){ }, where cMarker is initialized using prototype like this cMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

Comment: It hasn't been there before your edit. However, now it's not clear what exactly `tooltip` is, post the complete code

Comment: yeah, please check now, I edited it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the `draw`-method on your own, it will be called automatically when:

1. you add the overlay to the map
2. the viewport of the map changes

The workflow when working with  `OverlayView` is the following:

1. call the constructor (`cMarker` in this case), in the constructor set the properties of the overlay(will be done via `this.setValues(opt_options);` in your code)
2. when you set the `map`-property of the overlay(should be done inside the constructor, because you want to draw the overlays initially) , the API will automatically call the `onAdd`-method
3. In the `onAdd`- method create the node (with the desired content and additionally added event-listeners) and add it to a MapPane
4. the draw-method is called automatically(as I said initially after `onAdd()` or when the viewport changes). Use this method only to update the CSS-position(or additionally the CSS-size, when you want the size to be dependant on the map-zoom)

This workflow ensures that:
  1. the mapPanes are ready when `onAdd()` will be called
  2. the projection is available when `draw()` will be called

When you want to break out of this predefined execution-order listen to the panes_changed-event of the overlay, when it fires the panes and projection are available, you may add the overlay to the map

```
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(yourOverlayInstance,'panes_changed',
   function(){/*create node with content and events , 
                add it to a pane ,
                set position and optinally the size*/});
```

But this kind of custom implementation makes no sense, because the draw-method will be called automatically when the projection is available.